# Unable to load data from the xml in php

Tags: php, xml

XML is working as expected in my localhost but when i tried to load the data from the online server its failed to load.

XML -> `xml feed`

Code

```
<?php
$xmldata = simplexml_load_file("xml feed") or die("Failed to load your file");
foreach($xmldata->children() as $empl) {         
    $offering_type = $empl->offering_type;  
    $reference_number = $empl->reference_number;   
    $price = $empl->price; 
    $price = (int)$price;

    $city = $empl->city; 
<------- html code here to display the xml data ---->

?>
```

It failed to load xml feed and returned "failed to load your file"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the hosting server. After enabling File_Open=on. I can able to access the data.